# Adjust color where element has opacity

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a site where colors are associated with different users.

The user has a border around their profile pic for example, which uses their defined color.

The users color can also be placed on top of a portion of a background image, and when used in this way, the color is set to have a transparency so the image is viewable through the color.

Here's an example of the issue 
Example https://jsfiddle.net/hgoc6rmL/

When overlaid on a background, the color no longer matches the user color due to the colors in the background. When this is used on the site, it is actually within an SVG, which a canvas element behind.

My SVG is colored via

```
<linearGradient id="solids">
   <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(255, 80, 15);"></stop>
   <stop offset="1.6988004382071917%" style="stop-color: rgb(255, 80, 15);"></stop>
   <stop offset="1.6988004382071917%" style="stop-color: rgb(10, 10, 255);"></stop>
   <stop offset="1.6988004382071917%" style="stop-color: rgb(10, 10, 255);"></stop>
   <stop offset="19.97443202796756%" style="stop-color: rgb(10, 10, 255);"></stop>
   <stop offset="19.97443202796756%" style="stop-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);"></stop>
</linearGradient>
```

Is there a way with HTML, CSS or in the SVG to fix the color balance of the overlay so it closely matches the user color?

Comment: You can set stop-color properties in CSS instead of inline if you want.

Comment: Think about what you are asking.  You are placing a semi-transparent colour over a (presumably) multi-color background.  Your blob of colour is obviously going to vary in colour depending on the background.  So which part of it should match the original colour?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau yes, that is what I'm asking. People often come up with creative ways of doing this. Can I just saturate the colors to balance them? Is there a way to capture the colors of the background behind an svg and convert them to black and white? Are there other creative solutions out there?

Comment: @RobertLongson I change the stop-color quite regularly, which is why it is inline instead of being defined in external css

Comment: Assuming you had a black and white background. My point is do you want the colour to match when it is over the white part of the background, or when it is over the black part of the background?  How could you possibly choose an overlay colour that satisfies both requirements?

Comment: If I knew the answer, I wouldn't be asking the question :P I figured I'm probably not the first person to attempt this. My current plan of attack is rather than provide an opacity, to user a perforated pattern where I can apply the color the 'material' portion, yet still potentially see the background through. The effect I am going for is to have the two elements somewhat bleed together.